# Why is 2-ethylpentane is not a valid IUPAC name, but 3-ethylpentane is?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

I'm currently writing all the names of alkanes having molecular formula $\ce{C7H16}$. I wish to ask why 2-ethylpentane is not a valid IUPAC name, but 3-ethylpentane is?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. We’d like you to take the [Tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize with the site. Also, let us know what have you done so far to solve this specific problem. It’d help us to answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

Due to IUPAC conventions, the main alkane name is based on its longest chain. Here is an image showing different chain lengths for both alkanes. The numbers denote the longest alkane chain:

[image: Alkanes]

As you can see, 3-ethylpentane is symmetrical; no matter what chain you count along, the longest chain will always be 5 carbons long (pentane), and the ethyl group will always be on the third carbon (3-ethyl). Together, this is 3-ethylpentane.

However, if you look at '2-ethylpentane', there's a new longest chain which isn't 5 carbons long anymore. The image shows a new chain which is actually 6 carbons long (hexane), and there's now a methyl group on the third carbon (3-methyl). Together, this is 3-methylhexane. Because of this, '2-ethylpentane' isn't a real structure, since drawing it will leave you with 3-methylhexane as shown in the image.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Draw the structure of what you described as "2-ethylpentane" first. Then name it according to IUPAC rules. Does IUPAC name is same as "2-ethylpentane"?

Now, draw 3-methylhexane structure. How many ways you can name it? But only name count is its IUPAC name, which is 3-methylhexane.

Comment: I'd recommend not posting answers which are solely hints. We [haven't reached a real consensus on this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3661/16683), but generally hints do not fit into the SE mould, which is about building a library of knowledge in Q&A format. It is not supposed to be a forum with back-and-forth discussion between the question asker and you, nor is it supposed to be a medium for tutoring. If you feel that a hint is more justified than a full answer, please do it as a comment.

Comment: @orthocresol That happens on Math.SE all the time

Comment: @Abcd Math.SE has their own way of doing things. They can do whatever they wish, but I would rather we not follow them.